# How can I find the minimum supported platform for a given Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am REALLY sorry to ask what may be a very elementary question.  I'm working with a code library written in C.  I've been building and running it using NDK version 8e.  Also using SDK 22, and the minimum execution platform is 8 (Froyo, I believe).

Now I've introduced the use of timerfd_create.  It looks like the earliest NDK that includes sys/timerfd.h is v20.  What does (or doesn't) this imply about the minimum execution platform?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NDK platform **android-21**, your library is guaranteed to load on devices that run Lollipop and higher. Even though `android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/unistd.h defines` **__NR_timerfd_create**, this functionality is most likely unavailable on lower platforms.

Comment: Here is what the NDK documentation says:

"Important Notes: The Android NDK can only be used to target Android system images running Android 1.5 (API Level 3) or later. The NDK only provides system headers for a very limited set of native APIs and libraries supported by the Android platform."

From this I infer that timerfd_create exists in the system image for Android 1.5 and up, and has only been made available via the NDK in these recent revisions.  Am I wrong?  How can I find out?

Comment: It's easier to check with emulator, than to go through the kernel sources. Again, there is no guarantee that some platforms do the same.